# Custom toggle switch stops working after three toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a custom toggle switch built with css.. I am trying to make some input tags disable after clicking on the toggle switch. So whenever I click the switch three times, it stops working, I cant seem to fathom why.

Here is the code.

```js
$('input[name="switch"]').change(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $('input[name="tin"], label[for="tin"]').prop('disabled', true);
        $('input[name="switch"]').prop('name', "tin");
        $('#tinSwitchText').hide().html("(This will attract an added cost)").fadeIn(1500);
      } else {
        $('input[name="tin"], label[for="tin"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $('input[name="switch"]').prop('name', "switch");
        $('#tinSwitchText').html('')
      }
  });
```

```html
<!-- Include jQuery. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group d-flex " >
  <span class="w-15 d-flex justify-content-end">
    <input value="Get TIN" type="checkbox" id="id-name--1" name="switch" class="switch-input">
    <label for="id-name--1" class="switch-label"></label>
  </span>
  <span class="w-85 d-flex justify-content-start">
    <label for="" >I dont have a TIN, I want to get one <br>
      <small><i id="tinSwitchText"></i></small> 
    </label>
  </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: the guilty line is `$('input[name="switch"]').prop('name', "tin");` by doing such, you make the checkbox disable itself after it has been renamed. Why do you want to rename it exactly? Remove the renaming lines and it will work. The second one `$('input[name="switch"]').prop('name', "switch");` is useless BTW because there are no elements named `"switch"` anymore at that point

Comment: you were close, change this `$('input[name="tin"], label[for="tin"]').prop('disabled', true);` to `$('input[name="tin"], label[for="tin"]').prop('disabled', false);` and ur good to go.

Comment: @Kaddath I am renaming it because if it is checked, i want a different value to be sent to the server

Comment: @RamondeVries I dont get how that solves the problem

Comment: You should not need that, IIRC, the value will be present server-side if checked, and will be missing if not checked. That should be enough for you to know if the checkbox has been checked or not.

Comment: You have solved my issue.. Thank you very much. It works perfectly now. I still dont get why the other one wasnt working though

Comment: @Kaddath can you place this as a full answer so i accept it?

Answer (score 0):

After having read through the comments & whatnot, I've made the assumption that this something along the lines of what you'd like to have?

I must say, it's a little unclear specifically what you're trying to achieve here, i.e. why are you setting the element's inner HTML value with an id of `tinSwitchText` to nothing, only to reset it? Surely it would be more efficient to just show/hide it.

```js
// Some function that will run when the input is checked.
const whenChecked = (input) => {
  $('input[name="tin"], label[for="tin"]').prop('disabled', input.checked);
  $(input).prop('name', "tin");
  $('#tinSwitchText').fadeIn(1500);
};


// Some function that will run when the input is unchecked.
const whenUchecked = (input) => {
  $('input[name="tin"], label[for="tin"]').prop('disabled', input.checked);
  $(input).prop('name', "switch");
  $('#tinSwitchText').hide();
};


// Some function to handle the input state change.
const onChangeHandler = (input) => input.checked ? whenChecked(input) : whenUchecked(input);


// Wait for the DOM to load.
$(document).ready(() => {
  const input = document.querySelector("input[name=switch]");
  input.onchange = () => onChangeHandler(input);
});
```

```html
<!-- Include jQuery. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group d-flex " >
  <span class="w-15 d-flex justify-content-end">
    <input value="Get TIN" type="checkbox" id="id-name--1" name="switch" class="switch-input">
    <label for="id-name--1" class="switch-label"></label>
  </span>
  
  <!-- 
     - I've set the content of $('#tinSwitchText') to the default value below, 
     - the reason being because in the example code you provided, there wasn't much
     - going on? It would either be hidden, or visible, and essentially in this 
     - solution, it maintains the same functionality, but by all means, feel free to 
     - change it as you like.
    -->
  <span class="w-85 d-flex justify-content-start">
    <label for="">I dont have a TIN, I want to get one <br>
      <small><i style="display:none" id="tinSwitchText">(This will attract an added cost)</i></small> 
    </label>
  </span>
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The guilty line is `$('input[name="switch"]').prop('name', "tin");` by doing such, you make the checkbox disable itself after it has been renamed. This is the detailled process:

1. this.checked is true, `input name="switch"` gets renamed `name="tin"`
2. this.checked is false, `input name="switch"` not found anymore
3. this.checked is true, input that was renamed `name="tin"` gets disabled

You also actually don't need to rename the input to detect a change in your server data. Due to the way checkboxes work, your field will be present in the input if checked, and will be missing if not checked. It should be enough to detect your value.

simply remove the lines `$('input[name="switch"]').prop('name', "tin");` and `$('input[name="switch"]').prop('name', "switch");`, then adapt your detection server-side.